# MySQL optimization query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, indexing, filesort

i have one MySQL issue. I have to optimize some queries on my website. One of them i have already done, but there are still some which i cannot resolve without your help.

I have a table called "news":

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `edited` smallint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `site` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `foreign_id` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `horizontal` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image_author` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `text_author` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `lang` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `redirect` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `lang` (`lang`,`status`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=47122 ;
```

as you can see i have two indexes: "lang" and "date"

I have tried some combinations of different indexes and this one has produced me the best results ... unfortunately only on my local computer. On the server i still have bad results. I want to say that the database is the same.

query:

```
SELECT id FROM news WHERE lang =  'en' AND STATUS =1 ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

localhost explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news  | index | lang          | date |       3 | NULL |   23 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

server explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |  key   | key_len |     ref     | rows  |            Extra            |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news  | ref  | status        | status |      13 | const,const | 15840 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

I have looked a lot of other similar topics, but unfortunately i cannot find any solution to work on my server. I will be very glad to here from you some solution with some explanation for that so i can optimize my other queries.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT id
FROM news
WHERE lang = 'en' AND STATUS =1
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The best index is one that contains all the fields used in the query (four fields in all).  The ordering in the index is by equality conditions in the `where` clause followed by the `order by` clause followed by other columns in the `select` clause.

So, try this index:  `ndws(leng, status, date, id)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the result now is the following: 1 SIMPLE news ref status status 13 const,const 15020 Using where; Using index. The rows are also much, but now is using where and index. This is better, right ?

Comment: @VeskoGeorgiev . . . Yes, I think that is better.  Is it running faster?

Comment: i cannot find out if it is faster, but the page is getting open very often and that causes a big processor time, because i have shared hosting. So i hope that will decrease that time. :)

Comment: The only elements of the index being used are lang and status based on your query.  Because the concatenated index is ordered the same as your where clause, it uses the index (based on the first two elements).  Adding date and id will yield no benefit in this case.  Your best case scenario in this is a sort with a ranged index scan.  The operation will first retrieve the id where the "where" clause works.  Then it will order by date, followed by the limit clause.  One issue is data distribution.  If there are only a few values for "lang", the index will still probably not be used.

Comment: If there are, likewise, only a few values for status, the index will most likely not be used.